# My two kids won't move to my new house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I am playing Skyrim. My two kids won't move to my new house in Riften. Before, the game gave me the option to tell them that it was time to move, but as soon as I bought the house it doesn't have that option anymore...?

Comment: Have you bought the Children's Bedroom upgrade? Children need a Child's Bed and chest before they can move into a house.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy a new house, to have your kids move there with you, the new house will need at least 3 things: A Child's Bedroom, a bed for each child, and at least one chest in the room. Make sure you have all three and then you should be able to move your children to the new house